# Getting the url of the android default browser

Tags: android, url, browser, mobile-webkit

I am trying to create an application in which will be notifying the user about the phishy websites.So for this i need to get the url which the user has opened in the default browser.

After a lot of google search and stackoverflow search i am not getting any idea how to develop the app.Can you guys help me ...how i could get the url entered by the user (just want the url accessed).

Or any other way round to develop this type of app in android.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can proceed the following way.You can read browser bookmarks.Then see the arrange pattern of the bookmarks.Maybe it is sorted according to the accessed time.So you can get what you need

Comment: thanks Rasel , we can access the bookmarks and history of browser but what i want is ....to get the url of the browser in real time ... as soon as the user enters a phishy url ..my app will give him a notification..that the url being accessed is a phisy url.